# How to open non .rda files in R

Tags: r, rda

I am trying to do some work for my thesis which has me using the R programming language (and the R app on Mac OS Lion) for the first time. I had to download the files [from here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE8607) to work with but none of the files comes in .rda or .r they all come in different file extensions. Can someone please tell me how to either convert or use these files?

Comment: Fix yourself a glass of your favorite beverage. Curl up in a comfy chair, point your browser [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html) and do some reading.

Comment: Which files do you need to use specifically? I looked at your link and is not clear to me.

Comment: @AndresT the ones under "Download family"

Comment: I think you may want to ask this question on the Bioconductor mailing list, unless there are other systems biologists / molecular geneticists hanging around here ...

Comment: Although I upvoted @Dason's suggestion it is clear that you also need to read more introductory material on R. Talk to your thesis supervisor to get further advice and look at the CRAN website for the "Contributed" documentation.

Comment: I definitely second the recommendation that @DWin gave.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/geo/) might be relevant to your interests.  Also note that if you click on the link on that page that says "Analyze with GEO2R" you can get an R script created for you that will do some of the legwork for you.  I would highly suggest reading the instructions on that page in order to get things prepared the way you want them to be.

Comment: That page you link to is using rather old versions of R (and bioconductor). The OP should really just go straight to the http://bioconductor.org site and start getting comfortable.